Using grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 - where is hash stored?
I am following this guide to set up a GRUB 2 password. I ran grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2, entered a password, and the hash was displayed on screen. Then I ran vim.
Oops.
Vim filled the whole terminal, so my hash was no longer on the screen. I can't scroll up to see it. It's lost. I'm fine with running grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 again, but I want to be sure: is the hash I made before stored anywhere? In a file, or written to anywhere besides stdout? Is there any way to retrieve it without running grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 again with the same input? I want to make sure I delete all copies of it except where it's supposed to be, because I don't want it to leak.
Ubuntu documentation says "[grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2] converts your desired password into a very long alphanumeric code which is placed in the GRUB 2 files." Where in the GRUB 2 files? I'm going hunting.
Thank you!

grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 just outputs the password hash to the standard output (i.e., your terminal, unless you redirect the output manually). If you were on a Linux console (e.g. tty2), then you can't scroll back (at least with recent kernels), therefore your hash would be gone. If you were in a "normal" terminal application you can just scroll back to find your hash.
When you run grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2, you then have to manually put it into the configuration files. You can for example create a script named 01_password in /etc/grub.d, with a content like this one:
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo 'set superusers="root"'
echo 'password_pbkdf2 root  grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX......'
echo 'export superusers'

This would mandate a login with a username of root and the specified hashed password for most operations, including booting an OS. If you want an entry to be freely accessible, you'd have to create your own versions of the other scripts in the same directory (e.g. 10_linux) to mark the entries you want with --unrestricted.
